# Make with Autodependencies for C++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have looked, and found a few answers that look like they're related to this question, but none seem to help.

It is the usual story - I have a folder of .hpp and .cpp files which I'd like to compile to .o files, and then only have files recompiled when files they depend on have been changed.

My current makefile is:

```
SRCS = $(shell find ../Includes/ -name "*.cpp")
DEPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(DEPS) $(OBJS)

# Create the dependency files
%.d : %.cpp
    clang++ -MM $< -o $@ -c -std=c++11

# Include the dependency files
include $(DEPS)

# Compile the source files
%.o : %.cpp
    clang++ -c -Wall -std=c++11 $< -o $@
```

I've run this a few times (so the dependency files exist before I run make, and should definitely exist when I include them). I've also tried adding %.d to the dependancies of %.o.

Basically all that happens at the moment is that 'touch'ing a .cpp causes the .o and .d files to be regenerated, and touching a .hpp file (that is listed in the .d files for other files) does nothing.

Example Dependency File:

```
SomeFile.o : ../Includes/SomeFile.cpp \
    ../Includes/SomeFile.hpp ../Includes/SomeOtherFile.hpp
```

Comment: In the dependency files, what directories are attached to the hpp filenames?

Comment: With the code I gave you, dependency files aren't being generated for the hpp files (I just gave that a try now, it doesn't seem to help), I've edited my question to give an example d file.

Comment: Perhaps SCONS would be a better tool for you - http://www.scons.org

Comment: Or [cmake](http://cmake.org)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the path issue, I find it more natural to create the dependencies along the way, i.e. with the `-MD` or `-MMD` flags. That way you don't need a rule to update the dependency file.

```
CPPFLAGS += -MMD

TARGET := hello

.DEFAULT: all
all: $(TARGET)

SRCS := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.cpp")
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

hello: $(OBJS)
        $(LINK.cc) -o $@ $^

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: I've written a commented tutorial on the subject once, which is still maintained (by others) at http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was creating rules for:

```
SomeFile.o : ...
```

Whereas I needed a rule for:

```
../Includes/SomeFile.o : ...
```

Thanks to NovaDenizen who set me on the right path.